# Java cast object[] to model

Tags: java, model-view-controller, casting, model, jtable

I want to know how to get a selected row of JTable into a model.

Now i got something like this.

```
    int selectedRowIndex = tabelSpelers.getSelectedRow();
    int selectedColumnIndex = tabelSpelers.getColumnCount();
    Object[] tableData = new Object[selectedColumnIndex];
    for (int j = 0 ; j < selectedColumnIndex; j++){
        tableData[j] = tabelSpelers.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex,j);
    }

    Speler selectedSpeler = (Speler) tableData;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, tableData);
```

Model looks like this:

```
public Speler(int speler_id, String voornaam, String achternaam, String adres, String postcode, String woonplaats, String telefoonnummer, String email, int rating, boolean isBekend)
```

Comment: How does your model class look like?

Answer (score 0):

Your best option, without further information, is explicit manual translation. Instead of:

```
Object[] tableData = new Object[selectedColumnIndex];
for (int j = 0 ; j < selectedColumnIndex; j++){
  tableData[j] = tabelSpelers.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex,j);
}
Speler selectedSpeler = (Speler) tableData;
```

which yields a ClassCastException on the last line, you would write:

```
Speler selectedSpeler = new Speler();
selectedSpeler.setFoo(tabelSpelers.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1));
selectedSpeler.setBar(tabelSpelers.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 2));
```

and so on, to populate each attribute of the selectedSpeler object.

However, you may prefer to [extend AbstractTableModel as in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378013/connect-a-list-of-objects-to-a-jtable) to back your table directly with Speler objects.

Answer (score 0):

It must be easier than use all your setters.

With JList you can just use this:

```
Speler selectedKlant = (Speler) this.listSpelers.getSelectedValue();
```

Isn't there any way to to this with Jtable?